# How to get the classes and all its methods documentation on a single page, in Sphinx rst documentation

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I am trying to document classes and their methods on a single page, but I am getting
either

1. Only the class docstring but not the docs of their methods at all.

or

2. Classes and their methods on separate pages.

The structure of the documentation I am following is as follows:

In `index.rst` I am using the following

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:

   brief_doc
```

Then in `brief_doc.rst`, I am using something like this,

```
Brief Documentation
====================

.. autosummary::
   :toctree: stubs
   :template: class.rst

   Class_1
   Class_2
```

Is it possible to automatically pull all the methods of these classes and document them on individual pages (i.e., For example, `Class_1` and all its methods on a single page)